# Retrieve list of yielded threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading

In java is there some API that helps with retrieval of yielded threads, I was trying to prepare some sample program to learn and see yielding clearly by listing the yielded threads, but couldn't.

One more doubt I have is that once yielded does the thread run again or runs from the point it stopped. As per my observations it starts from same stacktrace as the run is not called over and over again. Is it correct ?

Yielding makes the thread state to runnable but can it be differentiated from other threads that are in runnable state.

Or any other program that clearly states yielded threads. I am putting the sample I am working on too..

```
public class ThreadYieldDemo implements Runnable {

    Thread t;

    ThreadYieldDemo(String str) throws InterruptedException {

        t = new Thread(this, str);
        System.out.println(" State = "+t.getState()+" "+str);
        t.start();
        System.out.println(" State-1 = "+t.getState()+" "+str);
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Entry = "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"  State = "+Thread.currentThread().getState());
        Random random = new Random();
        int next = random.nextInt(10);
        if(next%2==0)
        {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("In: "+Thread.currentThread().getState());

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" yielded...");
            Thread.yield();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("yield = "+Thread.currentThread().getState());
        }   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new ThreadYieldDemo("Thread 1");
        new ThreadYieldDemo("Thread 2");
        new ThreadYieldDemo("Thread 3");
        new ThreadYieldDemo("Thread 4");
        new ThreadYieldDemo("Thread 5");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and look at the threads in your IDE? Does it tell you anything there?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in code.

But you can use [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html) or profiler which may show you more details. But I still think that it won't show you if a thread is yielded...